# Using form to update has_many through join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am short of implementation ideas for my rails project. at this point it seems impossible to implement in rails.

I am cloning a sort of accounting software into a web app using rails framework for small manufacturing companies to keep track of their products stock in their different distribution branches.

I have 3 different models: "**Product**", "**Branch**" & "**Accumulator**"

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :accumulators
has_many :products, :through => :accumulators

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :accumulators
has_many :branches, :through => :accumulators

  def self.search(search)
   if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  end
end

class Accumulator < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :branch
end
```

I am new to rails and after reading up on many to many associations I came across using collections to add products to a branch "@branch.products << Product.all"

Is there a possible way to use a form "number_field_tag" in the branch show view to add multiple of specific products into the join table?

eg 
I want to add 10 of (Product) called "garden eggs" to a (Branch) called "lagos branch" to the (Accumulator) join table using a form in Branches show view?

Comment: I strongly advise against using has_and_belongs_to_many, no way to for example validate.

Can you explain the relationship a bit more?

If you add 10 "garden eggs" to "lagos branch", does that mean that "lagos branch".products should return 10 unique "garden eggs" or should it return "garden eggs" with "count : 10"?

Comment: Yh it should return "garden eggs" with "count: 10" for that specific branch

Comment: Please see my answer below 

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations for choosing `:has_many, through:` you will not regret it.

Is the relationship between a `product` and a `branch` static? 
Or does it change a lot?

In your `Accumulator` model, add an `integer` field called `amount` (count can have conflicts). Then you either create a form for your `Accumulators` or you add a **nested form** with for example [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

This way you can add `Accumulators` to your `Branch` with a certain `Product` and a certain `amount`.

Off topic:

Here is an article about why `has_many through` has some advantages:
http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

If you have problems with forms I can really recommend [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and for nice Javascript-assisted fields I recommend [Select2](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails).

Comment: Ok fair enough I get what you mean but now I want it to scale i.e if you add accumulators with a specific product maybe "garden eggs" and amount and later want to add more of that specific product "garden eggs", it should add to the previous amount if you get what I mean?

Comment: The way I have setup Cocoon before you get this behavior. You list all connected Accumulators as well as having the ability to add new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If the table `accumulators` needs to save only two things: `product_id`, and `branch_id`, you can easily use `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations.

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, join_table: 'accumulators'
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :branches, join_table: 'accumulators'
end
```

And now, there is no need for the third model.

As far as it goes, how to add a relationship, it's pretty easy in this case:

```
branch = Branch.last
branch.products << Product.create # you don't need to touch the middle table.
```

Instead of using `number_field_tag` to ask for plain ids, you can use something fancy like [jQuery Chosen Plugin](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-chosen.php). This plugin will allow you to use tag like input, and will send the ids to the server separated by `,`'s.

Comment: Using HABTM will not allow validation, callbacks or extra attributes - it is hard to know if you need this in the beginning of your modeling.